# Finding the derivative using the chain rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I am trying to find the derivative with respect to T of:
$$\frac FV(T_{\mathrm{in}} - T)+\beta k_0 \exp\left(-\frac{EaR}{T}\right)\left(C_{A,\mathrm{in}}+\frac{1}{\beta}\left(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T\right)\right)\left(C_{B,\mathrm{in}}+\frac{2}{\beta}\left(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T\right)\right).$$

This is what I came up with:
$$-\frac FV + \frac{\beta k_0 EaR \exp\left(-\frac{EaR}{T}\right)C_{A,\mathrm{in}}\cdot C_{B,\mathrm{in}}}{T^2} - 2\left(C_{A,\mathrm{in}}+\frac{1}{\beta}\left(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T\right)\right) - \left(C_{B,\mathrm{in}}+\frac{2}{\beta}\left(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T\right)\right).$$

Obviously the derivative of $\frac FV \left(T_{\mathrm{in}} - T\right)$ is $-\frac FV$.

And the derivative of the terms $C_{A,\mathrm{in}}+\frac{1}{\beta}\left(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T\right)$ and $C_{B,\mathrm{in}}+\frac{2}{\beta}\left(T_{\mathrm{in}}-T\right)$ are $-\frac{1}{\beta}$ and $-\frac{2}{\beta}$ respectively.

The derivative of $\beta k_0 \exp\left(-\frac{EaR}{T}\right)$ is

$$\frac{\beta k_0 (-EaR)}{T^2}.$$

From there I simply use the chain rule to gather it all, but I just can't figure whether I got it right. Can anyone give me a second opinion on the derivative?

Thanks

Comment: Why didn' you accept the editing with $$(F/V)\cdot(T_{in} - T)+\beta\cdot k_0\cdot \exp(-E_aR/T)\cdot\left(C_{A,in}+\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)\cdot\left(C_{B,in}+\frac{2}{\beta}*(T_{in}-T)\right)$$

Comment: Sorry - I think I was editing myself when the edit came. My bad. I would gladly accept the above at it is way more readable than what I wrote

Comment: Yes I think it is much better and readble!

Comment: Yea, my bad. Looking at my first post I just thought I ought to fill in a bit more of the reasoning of my solution, so I just started editing right after posting it. I wasn't even aware that others could suggest edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should have

$$-(F/V)+\\
+(E_aR/T^2)\cdot\beta\cdot k_0\cdot \exp(-E_aR/T)\cdot\left(C_{A,in}+\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)\cdot\left(C_{B,in}+\frac{2}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)+\\
+\beta\cdot k_0\cdot \exp(-E_aR/T)\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{\beta}\right)\cdot\left(C_{B,in}+\frac{2}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)+\\
+\beta\cdot k_0\cdot \exp(-E_aR/T)\cdot\left(C_{A,in}+\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{2}{\beta}\right)$$

which can be reordered as

$$-(F/V)+\beta\cdot k_0\cdot \exp(-E_aR/T)\cdot\\\left[(E_aR/T^2)\cdot\left(C_{A,in}+\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)\cdot\left(C_{B,in}+\frac{2}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)+
\left(-\frac{1}{\beta}\right)\cdot\left(C_{B,in}+\frac{2}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)+
\left(C_{A,in}+\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot(T_{in}-T)\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{2}{\beta}\right)\right]$$

---

Note that the expression is in the form

$$f(T)=a(T)+b(T)\cdot c(T)\cdot d(T)$$

therefore

$$f'(T)=a'(T)+b'(T)\cdot c(T)\cdot d(T)+b(T)\cdot c'(T)\cdot d(T)+b(T)\cdot c(T)\cdot d'(T)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @user!
I think I kind of entangled it somewhere. I'll just spend a couple of minutes going through it all again

Comment: @ChuckNoise You are welcome! I can't edit your question at the moment since there is another editing to be approved. Bye

Comment: @ChuckNoise We have the four terms I've indicated,from here we can simplify something of course.